# Change posts_per_page with button/input

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I know there's a wordpress stackexchange but yeah, no ones helping.

I was wondering if it was possible to change the number of posts emitted from a custom loop based on a button form?

What I gathered so far (test values):

```
<form method="post">
    <button class="amt-button" name="amt_per" value="1">1</button>
    <button class="amt-button" name="amt_per" value="3">3</button>
    <button class="amt-button" name="amt_per" value="0">0</button>
    <button class="amt-button" name="amt_per" value="-1">all</button>
</form>


<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Postsperpage
    $('button.amt-button').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Also the WP_Query (the $args):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'product',
    'posts_per_page' => $postperpage,

    'product_cat'=>'product',
    'product_tag'=>'apparel',

    'orderby'=>$orderby,
    'order'=>$order,
    'meta_key'=>$meta_key,
    'paged' => $paged
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
$postsperpage = isset($_POST['amt_per'])? $_POST['amt_per']: -1;
```

Then in your `WP_Query` arg

```
'posts_per_page' => $postsperpage
```